# Change diagonals of an array of matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, octave

I have an application with an array of matrices. I have to manipulate the diagonals several times. The other elements are unchanged. I want to do things like:

```
for j=1:nj
  for i=1:n
      g(i,i,j) = gd(i,j)
   end
 end
```

I have seen how to do this with a single matrix using logical(eye(n)) as a single index, but this does not work with an array of matrices. Surely there is a way around this problem. Thanks

Comment: In my own opinion I would just create the Identity matrix and use that to manipulate the diagonals

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Then please prepare an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Luis Mendo's answer, a version that may perhaps be more easy to modify depending on one's specific purposes. No doubt his version will be more computationally efficient though.

```
g = rand(3,3,2); % example data
gd = [1 4; 2 5; 3 6]; % example data. Each column will go to a diagonal
sz = size(g); % Get size of data
sub = find(eye(sz(1))); % Find indices for 2d matrix

% Add number depending on location in third dimension.
sub = repmat(sub,sz(3),1); %  
dim3 = repmat(0:sz(1)^2:prod(sz)-1, sz(1),1); 
idx = sub + dim3(:);

% Replace elements.
g(idx) = gd;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I wish there was a more readable way to do this. I kept wanting some method to collapse the first two indices down to one. I suppose I could reshape G but that would probably result in a lot of copying of data, since I would have to reshape it back again.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [linear index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) as follows:

```
g = rand(3,3,2); % example data
gd = [1 4; 2 5; 3 6]; % example data. Each column will go to a diagonal
s = size(g); % size of g
ind = bsxfun(@plus, 1:s(1)+1:s(1)*s(2), (0:s(3)-1).'*s(1)*s(2)); % linear index
g(ind) = gd.'; % write values
```

Result:

```
>> g
g(:,:,1) =
   1.000000000000000   0.483437118939645   0.814179952862505
   0.154841697368116   2.000000000000000   0.989922194103104
   0.195709075365218   0.356349047562417   3.000000000000000
g(:,:,2) =
   4.000000000000000   0.585604389346560   0.279862618046844
   0.802492555607293   5.000000000000000   0.610960767605581
   0.272602365429990   0.551583664885735   6.000000000000000
```

Comment: +1: I've really tried hard to get a shorter solution but... And I would give a second +1 for using `.'` as transpose

Comment: @Andy Thanks! I always use that; I am very much against using `'` for transpose, even for real numbers

Answer (score 0):

Are we already playing code golf yet? Another slightly smaller and more readable solution

```
g = rand(3,3,2);
gd = [1 4; 2 5; 3 6];
s = size(g);
g(find(repmat(eye(s(1)),1,1,s(3))))=gd(:)

g =

ans(:,:,1) =

1.00000   0.35565   0.69742
0.85690   2.00000   0.71275
0.87536   0.13130   3.00000

ans(:,:,2) =

4.00000   0.63031   0.32666
0.33063   5.00000   0.28597
0.80829   0.52401   6.00000
```